# jquery mobile preventing page render

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I have a very simple jquery mobile application:

- `/index.html` (contains a link to `home.html`)
- `/home.html`

I want `home.html` to only be visible for users who satisfy a prerequisite (e.g local storage should contain a `logged=true`). Otherwise I want them to be redirected back to `index.html`. Of course I want this to happen either when the user clicks on the link from `index.html` or if he/she navigates directly to `home.html` via the URL.

In order to enforce this I have the following in an external script which is inluded in all pages:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforecreate', function(e) {
    if (!userIsLoggedIn() && e.target.id=='home_page') {
        $.mobile.changePage('index.html');
    }
});
```

Note that my `home.html` starts with `<div home-role="page" id="home_page">`

This code works but the problem is that the user gets to see the contents of `home.html` for an instant. I've seen in the [API](http://api.jquerymobile.com/category/events/) that `pagebeforecreate` is the earliest event that is being called on a page transition. Calling the `changePage` though doesn't stop from further events to being called on this page that I don't want users to see.

How can I completely stop the rendering of `home.html` and immediatelly redirect user back to `index.html`?

Answer (score 0):

follow is just idea adding your code.

1. make a page invisible by default in "home.html".
2. check logged in when "home_page" is at 'pagebeforecreate'.
3. if logged, make page to be visible.
4. if no, change to index.html

but, this is just hide a page to unlogged person, not really secure.
it's still opened to get a HTML Plain code from URL.

Answer (score 0):

This will help you to prevent jquery mobile from rendering page.

```
jQuery(document).on('mobileinit', function(){ jQuery.mobile.autoInitializePage = false; });
```